# add userid to next json file

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-cloud

Unfortunately I am not that familiar with json docs so I have a bit of a problem appending or concat some data.
I have some code that goes to the website to return users data after authorisation.  The code below will insert user info into a cloudant database via json doc and then gets the associated users dir data and inserts into the databse in a json format.  Unfortunately the dir data does not contain the userid so I believe I would need to add this to the json doc so that I can display the user id and dir data in a report via dashdb.

```js
// On return with the authorization code now available
app.get('/oauth_callback', function(req, res) {
  var code = req.query.code;
  request("https://deviceurl/?client_id=1234&client_secret=678&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://myurl/oauth_callback&code=" + code, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
      var access_token = jsonObject.AccessToken;
      var user_id = jsonObject.UserID;
      // use the returned userid and access token to get the users profile data in json format
      request("https://deviceurl/user/" + user_id + ".json/?client_id=1234&client_secret=678&redirect_uri=https://myurl/oauth_callback&access_token=" + access_token + "&some other tokens", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var usrinf = JSON.parse(body);
          //inserts into my cloudant database 1 json doc
          mydb.insert({
            'User_Info': (body)
          });
          console.log(body);
          res.send(body); // send raw data back to web page just to show its working
        }
        //while the access token is still active get some dir data
        request("https://deviceurl/user/" + user_id + "/dir.json/?client_id=1234&client_secret=678&redirect_uri=https://myurl/oauth_callback&access_token=" + access_token + "&some other tokens", function(error, response, body) {
            var dirinf = JSON.parse(body);
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              //inserts in cloudant dir data but need to include id so I know the user
              mydb.insert({
                'DIR': (dirinf) + ’‘+(user_id)
              });
              console.log(body);
              // res.send(body); // not doing this as not necessary
            } else {
              res.send("Error in Dir request");
            }
          })
          //else{
          //    res.send("Error in UsInf request");
          // }
      })
    } else {
      res.send("error in authorise token request")
    }
  })
});
```

As the user_id is in a var I thought I could just tack it on but this does not appear to work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error output, if any, do you get?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You can't debug all your code at once, and don't ask us to do it for you. Break it in pieces,  unit test, isolate the problem. And post back here a specific question, providing all the details to reproduce it. We will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that team. I did a bit more research last night and found it wasn't that hard to add the user_id from the url as an additional line in the JSON output once I got the JSON concepts in my head. Once I assign the JSON body to the variable I can then add another element and assign the user_id to it.
So the code snippet looks like this.

```
 function (error, response, body) {
                            //assign the JSON body to a variable
                            var dirinf=JSON.parse(body);
                            //add an element for userid and add the user_id
                            dirinf["userid"]=user_id;
```

Thanks once again.